# if I add jaxws-2.2 giving org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener error

Tags: java, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-liberty

If I add I add `jaxws-2.2` feature in my server.xml, its giving **org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener error**. Can anyone let me know what I'm missing here?
If I add `<feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>` my code is working fine but if I add 
`<feature>javaee-7.0</feature>` , it gives same the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) 
  at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:218) 
  ... 110 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener.() 
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) .
```

Here are the features I have enabled:

```
<featureManager> 
  <feature>javaee-7.0</feature> 
  <!-- <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature> --> 
  <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature> 
  <feature>servlet-3.1</feature> 
  <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature> 
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature> 
  <feature>jsp-2.3</feature> 
  <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature> 
  <feature>jsf-2.2</feature> 
  <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature> 
</featureManager>
```

Comment: not enough information here to give a proper answer.  Can you please include your full server.xml configuration (minus any sensitive data) as well as the full stack trace of the Exception?

Comment: <server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-7.0</feature> 
       <!--  <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature> -->
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
      <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature> 
    </featureManager>

Comment: Hi Andy, Please find my server.xml copied above, i removed my datasource configurations.

Comment: I verified all of the features you have mentioned load successfully together in Liberty 17.0.0.3.  You will need to provide more details on what your application is doing to cause this condition, including a full stack trace.